# Does JBoss EAP 6 support @LocalBinding EJB annotation?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, migration

I am in the process of migrating an application from JBoss EAP 5.1 to 6.3. I am resolving compilation errors and one that i am getting right now is

```
 package org.jboss.ejb3.annotation does not exist
[javac] import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.LocalBinding;
```

I did a bit of digging around and from what i gather, they say that in javaee6, they discontinued this to standardize the ejb namespaces. 
Is this true? 
Some background information on this would help as well

Comment: FYI - check the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the JBoss issue [AS7-3015](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-3015), JBoss *...no longer supports binding to custom JNDI names for EJBs*.

The same information is also mentioned, at least, in two more JBoss forum discussion threads:

- [Overload EJB jndi binding but @LocalBinding not found](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/176194?tstart=0)
- [Custom JNDI Names](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/177380?tstart=0)

Therefore, the EJBs are only bounded to *java:global*, *java:app*, *java:module* namespaces as mandated by the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/girgn/index.html).